# PHP - How to fix date_format() error 'boolean given, instead of DateTimeInterface'?

Tags: php, date, date-format

I'm getting this error:
"Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in C:...\myFile.php on line 24"

I've tried that code using strtotime instead of time():

```
$strDate = time();
$str = strtotime($strDate);
$date = date_create($str);
echo date_format($date, "Y/m/d");
```

And works: //--> 2018/12/31

But can't understand why, because both strtotime, and time return same Unix timestamps.

```
$dtObj = date_create(time(), timezone_open("Europe/Oslo"));
echo $dtObj . '</br>'; // Works ok
date_format($dtObj, "d-m-Y"); // This throws error
```

I expected the same result wiht both codes. Any clue about what's happening?

Comment: strtotime is returning false, because you're passing an integer in. `$strDate` is already a time. `strtotime` expects a string, such as `'2018-12-30'`. `date_create` does the same in your second bit of code, because it expects a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_create()` expects as first parameter a **string** representing date and time.

Passing a number as you do (*you pass `time()` that return the unix timestamp*) will result in `date_create` returning `false` that of course cannot be parsed by `date_format()`.

You can read the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) to see how the data string can be formatted.

You can pass `"now"` if you want to create a DateTime object set to the present moment.

```
$dtObj = date_create( "now", timezone_open("Europe/Oslo"));
echo date_format($dtObj, "d-m-Y") . "<br>";
```

Comment: Ok, it seems that was the problem. Thank you.